# MongoDB aggregation: how to unwind an unknown number of nested arrays?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
{
   "name": "item1",
   "values": [<some array>],
   "subitems": [
      {
         "name": "item2",
         "values": [<some array>],
         "subitems": [
            {
               "name": "item3",
               "values": [<some array>],
               "subitems": [
                  {
                     "name": "item4",
                     "values": [<some array>],
                     "subitems": [
                        {
                           "name": "item5",
                           "values": [<some array>],
                           "subitems": [
                                <...and so on...>
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

So basically the "depth" of `subitems` is undetermined, and each `subitems` array might contain any number of elements.

If we unwind `subitems`, mongo unwinds only the `subitems` elements at `item1` level, which makes sense. However, I need it to go deeper into the hierarchy in a recursively manner.

How can we unwind all the nested `subitems`?

Comment: I don't think `unwind` goes recursive, you have to write a recursive function. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038857/mongodb-query-for-nested-elements-on-each-level/60076757#60076757

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for the replies.@DanieleTassone ultimately I want to concat all nested item names, e.g. "item1-item2-item3-item4". So unwind would help flattening the data so that I can loop through it.

Comment: Have you considered Mongodb MapReduce as a viable solution or are you forced to use aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

`$unwind` does not support recursive unwinding to my knowledge.

I had a similar problem where I had a document with nested elements, where each element had an ID and each element could have multiple elements, each with their own ID, and so on...

I needed a list of distinct ID's.

My problem was related to C# and I ended up retrieving the outer-most document and in the C# driver I implemented a function that traversed the retrived document recursively, which then returned a flattened list of distinct ID's.